# Project Euler #8

Tags: c++, strings, programming-challenge

I was doing [Project Euler #8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8), which asks:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
>   greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
>   the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

My solution:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ull unsigned long long int 
int main() {
// your code goes here
string s;
getline(cin,s);
ull max=0;
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{  
   ull prod=1;
   for(int j=i;j<13+i;j++)
   prod*=(s[j]-'0');
   if(prod>=max)
   max=prod;
 }
   cout<<max;
   return 0;
}
```

I have never done this type of question in which we have to read input as a string and than operate on it. I don't know if my approach is right or not. Can anyone point me out where I am wrong?

Answer (score 5):

When analyzing the digits near the end, `s[j]` will reference an address that is past the end of the string.

You could optimize the solution by taking advantage of the fact that if you have already computed

$$P_0 = a \cdot b \cdot c \cdot d \cdot e \cdot f \cdot g \cdot h \cdot i \cdot j \cdot k \cdot l \cdot m$$

then you could take a shortcut when computing

$$P_1 = b \cdot c \cdot d \cdot e \cdot f \cdot g \cdot h \cdot i \cdot j \cdot k \cdot l \cdot m \cdot n$$

since they share a lot of the same intermediate calculations.  In fact,

$$P_1 = \frac{P_0 \cdot n}{a}$$

… as long as \$a \ne 0\$.  (You would have to take care to handle zeroes as a special case.)

Comment: Being honest sir,i am not that technically good to understand what you said.If you don't mind can you make it some more clear.Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: So my solution is completely useless??

Comment: When you reference an address past the end of the string, anything could happen. Your program could crash. You could get a wrong answer. You might get lucky and get the right answer anyway.

Comment: what else can i do in my do so that it won't get crashed

Comment: Ensure that `j` is never greater than or equal to `s.length()`.

Comment: Hello again,i tried to debug my solution myself and found that the string length() i was inputting was 50 i.e only the first line of characters.But i think i am doing right as i am using getline().Can you explain me why its reading only first line even after using getline() method

Comment: `getline()` gets one line. That's why it's called `getline()`. We're veering off-topic for Code Review, though, when you're asking about how to fix your broken code.

Answer (score 3):

1. I would refrain from including `<bits/stdc++.h>`. This includes pretty much every single STL header which is certainly easier to use but in general you should only include what you actually need. It's also not a standard C++ header file and hence not portable.
2. `using namespace std` is generally [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
3. Instead of using `#define` you should use `typedef` (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591713/why-use-c-typedefs-rather-than-defines)).
4. Use spaces to declutter your code, i.e. instead of `for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)` it should be `for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)`. This increases readability.
5. Indent your code properly and consistently. Again this improves readability. This is especially important when you decide to omit braces for single line statements in `for` loops or `if` blocks like you did here:

   > ```
   > for(int j=i;j<13+i;j++)
   > prod*=(s[j]-'0');
   > if(prod>=max)
   > max=prod;
   > ```

   This should at least be:

   ```
   for (int j = i; j < 13 + i; j++)
       prod *= (s[j] - '0');
   if (prod >= max)
       max = prod;
   ```

   to make clear what belongs into which block. Better would be:

   ```
   for (int j = i; j < 13 + i; j++)
   {
       prod *= (s[j] - '0');
   }

   if (prod >= max)
   {
       max = prod;
   }
   ```

   Short code is not necessarily good code because it tends to obfuscate the meaning and is more prone to contain bugs.

Cleaned up the code looks like this:

```
#include <string>
typedef unsigned long long ull

int main()
{
    string s;
    std::getline(cin, s);
    ull max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {  
        ull prod = 1;
        for (int j = i; j < 13 + i; j++)
        {
            prod *= (s[j] - '0');
        }
        if (prod >= max)
        {
            max = prod;
        }
    }
    std::cout << max;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using `getline` since projecteuler.net only wants the answer.  The string can easily be part of your source:

```
string input = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
```

By breaking the input string into the sub strings that are in between the 0's(since any n digit combination that includes a 0 will result in a 0 for an answer) you can greatly reduce the number of multiplying operations.  This coupled with  200_success's suggestion will result in code something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

typedef unsigned long long ull;

ull FindMaxProduct(string input, int digits)
{
    ull maxProduct = 0;
    stringstream ss(input);
    string temp = "";
    while (getline(ss,temp,'0'))
    {
        int size = temp.length();
        if (size >= digits)
        {
            ull tempProduct = 1;
            int i = 0;
            for (; i < digits; i++)
            {
                tempProduct *= (temp[i] - '0');
            }
            if (tempProduct > maxProduct)
            {
                maxProduct = tempProduct;
            }
            for (; i < size; i++)
            {
                tempProduct = ((tempProduct / (temp[i - digits] - '0')) * (temp[i] - '0'));
            }
            if (tempProduct > maxProduct)
            {
                maxProduct = tempProduct;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxProduct;
}
```