# Project Euler 8 - Redux

Tags: c++, c++11, programming-challenge

Spurred by this question: [Project Euler #8](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82976/project-euler-8) I decided to try to solve it with as clean code as possible.

Here is the problem formulation:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
>   greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
>   the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

This is my implementation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

static const char* c_input = 
"73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"  
"96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"  
"85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
"12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"  
"66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"  
"62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"  
"30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
"70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"  
"65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"  
"52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
"53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"  
"83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"  
"82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"  
"16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
"17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"  
"24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"  
"07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"  
"84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
"05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"  
"71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

std::vector<std::string> partition(const std::string& input){
    std::vector<std::string> ans;

    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    while (pos < input.size()){
        auto first_non_zero = input.find_first_not_of('0', pos);
        // Only zeros left
        if (first_non_zero == std::string::npos)
            break;

        auto next_zero = input.find('0', first_non_zero);

        // No zeros left, assume end of string
        if (next_zero == std::string::npos)
            next_zero = input.size();

        ans.emplace_back(input.substr(first_non_zero, next_zero - first_non_zero));
        pos = next_zero;
    }
    return ans;
}

int toint(char digit){
    return digit - '0';
}

int main(int, char**){
    const auto problem_parts = partition(c_input);
    typedef decltype(problem_parts)::size_type size_type;
    const size_type num_digits = 13;
    uint64_t ans = 0;

    for (const auto& problem : problem_parts){
        if (problem.size() < num_digits)
            continue;

        uint64_t running_product = 1;
        for (size_type i = 0; i < num_digits; ++i){
            running_product *= toint(problem[i]);
        }

        for (size_type i = num_digits; i < problem.size(); ++i){
            // Carefull of rounding and overflow here, division first and then multiplication.
            running_product = running_product / toint(problem[i - num_digits]) * toint(problem[i]);
            if (running_product > ans)
                ans = running_product;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Answer: " << ans << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to improve this, nitpicking welcome.

Comment: What's your time?

Comment: Not sure what the partition() is doing. But Why not just keep 13 running totals. Then you just have to loop over the data once and you don't need the relatively expensive division.

Comment: @LokiAstari The running time is just about instant. It has linear time complexity in the size of the input string. The number of adjacent factors to consider doesn't affect the run time. The problem can be partitioned into smaller problems by realizing that all 0s will create a zero product around them. Thus splitting the input into subproblems by the zeros creates simpler problems to solve. I'm partitioning the problem as is commonly said. I do not understand your proposal of keeping 13 running totals, could you elaborate?

Comment: Your idea is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good the way you do not use `using namespace std;`.  This practice will save you a lot of headaches later on.

In fact, the only problem I found with this code is that you do not use braces around one-line `if` statements.

```
if (next_zero == std::string::npos)
    next_zero = input.size();
```

Using braces will not change the runtime behavior of your code, but it can help you prevent errors if you make a mistake, [like Apple did with their Apple SSL bug](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/).

Answer (score 3):

### Process once

In `partition` you are already touching every element in the string once, you might as well convert the character to an `int` here and return `std::vector<int>`. Thereby saving all the other `toInt` calls.

### Bug

I think you will miss the maximum product if it's in the first 13 digits of a partition, in the first for loop you prime `running_product` with 13 digits (index 0 through 12), entering the second for loop `ans` is the result from the last partition, or zero, but at the 'if' check `running_product` is looking at digits (index 1 through 13). Therefore the result of indices 0-12 is never used as `ans`. Also if the partition has exactly `num_digits` digits `ans` would be not checked.

```
    uint64_t running_product = 1;
    for (size_type i = 0; i < num_digits; ++i){
        running_product *= toint(problem[i]);
    }

    if (running_total > ans) ans = running_total;

    for (size_type i = num_digits; i < problem.size(); ++i){
       ...
    }
```

Adding another check is a quick fix for this.

### Avoid no brace blocks

This is a little bit of a taste issue, the one line block without braces is something that may cause hard to find errors when dealing with older code or multiple team members. If you do it be consistent (There is one loop that has braces with one line, most of the others don't. When it is used I personally prefer to have the statement in one line rather than in two making it a better indication that this is a one liner. E.g.

```
if (first_non_zero == std::string::npos) break;
```

### Allocations

This is a small euler example, what you are doing is perfectly fine, in a larger scope for a case like this, i'd prefer an algorithm that doesn't have to allocate space again for most of the incoming data. You could easily modify the lower loop to recalculate your `running_total` when hitting a zero, yes that might cause more multiplications and test but allocations are a bigger drain than multiplication.

Just determining the partition size rather than actually physically partitioning the string into substring what have the same effect without the allocations.

Answer (score 2):

### Standard types aren't necessarily in the global namespace

```
#include <cstdint>
```

You can't subsequently use `std::uint64_t` without qualification.  You could bring it in (within the `main()` function):

```
using std::uint64_t;
```

It would give the compiler a little more latitude (and get us back to not depending on optional features), however to write:

```
using result_type = std::uint_fast64_t;
```

(We only care that we can hold any number up to 9^13, i.e. 2,541,865,828,329, or 43 bits).

### Bug: `size_type` isn't what you think

You seem to be using the size type of a vector as the size type of its elements:

```
typedef decltype(problem_parts)::size_type size_type;
const size_type num_digits = 13;
```

I think what's meant is

```
typedef decltype(problem_parts)::value_type::size_type size_type;
const size_type num_digits = 13;
```

Or, in modern language,

```
using size_type = decltype(problem_parts)::value_type::size_type;
```

### Reduce the number of strings used

The `partition()` function is clear and obvious.  But it does take its input as a `std::string` and it does create a whole vector of `std::string` before you start any of the calculations.  You could avoid a bunch of copying by accepting input as a C-style string and by producing each output on demand, rather than all at once in a collection.

A quick win would be to use `string_view` objects in place of the strings that are collected in the vector:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <cstring>

std::vector<std::string_view> partition(const char *input) {
    const char *const input_end = input + std::strlen(input);

    std::vector<std::string_view> ans;
    ans.reserve(1 + (input_end - input) / 10); // Assume digits uniformly distributed, and round up

    for (auto pos = input;  pos != input_end;  ) {
        auto first = std::find_if(pos, input_end, [](const char c){ return c != '0';});
        pos = std::find(first, input_end, '0');

        if (pos != first)
            ans.emplace_back(first, pos - first);
    }

    return ans;
}
```

With no other changes to the program, this eliminates a bunch of small allocations:

```
before:   total heap usage: 28 allocs, 28 frees, 83,358 bytes allocated

after:    total heap usage:  3 allocs,  3 frees, 75,344 bytes allocated
```

Similarly, you could avoid creating and adding "short" strings to the result vector; the trade-off is that you have to move the knowledge of what's "short" through to `partition()`.  See the final worked example.

### Use a simpler `main()` declaration

We can just use the form that takes no arguments, since we don't accept any command-line arguments:

```
int main()
```

### Spelling mistake

The comment should read

```
// Careful of rounding and overflow here, ...
```

(only one 'l' in 'careful').  You did ask for for some nitpicking, after all!

Note that you don't really need any care about overflow - even if you multiply first, you still have at least 18 bits of headroom (roughly 806,351 times as much as you need).  Rounding would only be an issue if you were to write

```
        running_product *= toint(problem[i]) /  toint(problem[i - num_digits]);
```

Separate `*=` and `/=` would be fine, of course.

---

## Worked example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

static auto const c_input =
    "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
    "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
    "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
    "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
    "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
    "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
    "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
    "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
    "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
    "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
    "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
    "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
    "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
    "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
    "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
    "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
    "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
    "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
    "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
    "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

std::vector<std::string_view> partition(const char *input, std::size_t min_length) {
    auto const input_end = input + std::strlen(input);

    std::vector<std::string_view> ans;
    ans.reserve(1 + (input_end - input) / 10); // Assume digits uniformly distributed, and round up

    for (auto pos = input;  pos != input_end;  ) {
        auto const first = std::find_if(pos, input_end, [](const char c){ return c != '0';});
        pos = std::find(first, input_end, '0');

        std::size_t length = pos - first;
        if (length >= min_length)
            ans.emplace_back(first, length);
    }

    return ans;
}

int main() {
    using result_type = std::uint_least64_t;

    std::size_t num_digits = 13;
    auto const problem_parts = partition(c_input, num_digits);
    using size_type = decltype(problem_parts)::value_type::size_type;
    result_type ans = 0;

    for (const auto& problem : problem_parts) {
        result_type running_product = 1;
        for (size_type i = 0;  i < problem.size();  ++i) {
            running_product *= problem[i] - '0';
            if (i >= num_digits)
                running_product /= problem[i - num_digits] - '0';
            if (running_product > ans)
                ans = running_product;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Answer: " << ans << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```